# How to create an iframe that can change its page

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, href

This is best explained with an example:
I have a main.html, example1.html, example2.html

In main.html i have two links, to example1 and example2, below the links i have an iframe box.
Is there a way to click example1 so it appears in the iframe box and when i click to example2 the iframe changes to that?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use javascript.

Comment: i see, so i cant' do it purely with html, thanks man.

Comment: tried designMode/contentEditable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to click on a link within main.html and then load the href of that link into an iframe?

If so, you don't need JavaScript to do that, you can use the target attribute and name your frame, e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="myFrame">Example 1</a><br />
<a href="http://www.bing.com" target="myFrame">Example 2</a><br />
<br />
<iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

For a working example of the above, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/BLG7U/1/

Comment: Didn't know target could do such thing, really helpful, thanks man.

Comment: I also just checked target attribute and it explicitly states you can target an iframe, it really went over my head.